# simple questions of callbacks with and without an array function

Tags: reactjs, callback

i have a simple question that has border me for a very long time. so can anyone tell me what is the difference between onClick{()=> function()}} and onClick{function()}? what is the difference between having a arrow function and without an arrow function? and are these two function both callback functions?

Comment: This is fundamental. Try to find out by research in will make you understand deeper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant more what is the difference between `onClick={() => callback()}` and `onClick={callback}` (*notice sans `()`*). If you did `onClick={callback()}` then the callback would be invoked immediately and ***not*** when the click occurs.

- `onClick={() => callback()}`: An anonymous function is created each time the component is rendered
- `onClick={callback}`: A "reference" to the callback function is passed each render cycle instead

There isn't much of a difference between the two other than if using the direct reference version it ***will*** also be passed the `onClick` event, but if the callback doesn't take any arguments anyway this isn't an issue. With the anonymous function there may be higher memory usage (since each component receives a copy of the callback) and some *marginal* performance hit in constructing the copies.

Using an anonymous callback function allows for other arguments to be passed

```
onClick={() => callback(customArg)}
```

Or you can proxy the event object ***and*** pass other args

```
onClick={event => callback(event, customArg)}
```

You can achieve a similar effect with a direct reference by creating a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) callback function. This allows you to still pass additional arguments ***and*** the `onClick` event

```
const callback = customArg => event => {...}
...
onClick={callback(customArg)}
```